# How to create dynamic sub-domain in codeigniter using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, php

How to create dynamic sub domain in ***codeigniter*** using ***htaccess*** ?

Say i have an example link:

```
www.example.com/page/getpage/user1.
```

This link displays all the details of 'user1' and i want to change it to 'user1.example.com'

My project creates subdomains for each user using htaccess. For example user1.example.com redirects to www.example.com/getuser/user1 using .htaccess. my issue is that codeigniter creates new session after a post

Using .htaccess redirect i am getting the server ip address not the user ip address. How can i get user ip address than server ip. I am using codeigniter3.0

Any help in doing this appreciated.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code *should* already suffice. I recommend simply calling var_dump($_SERVER) to see which fields will help you for your application.

Particularly, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will be helpful.  Try this:

```
$parts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

if(count($parts) != 3){
    die('this application requires a subdomain');
}

$this->subdomain = array_shift($parts);
```

If you add that to a base controller, then extend all of your controllers from the base controller, you'll have access to that subdomain variable in all of your controllers.

Comment: My project creates subdomains for each user using htaccess. For example user1.example.com redirects to www.example.com/getuser/user1 using .htaccess. my issue is that codeigniter creates new session after a post

Using .htaccess redirect i am getting the server ip address not the user ip address. How can i get user ip address than server ip

Comment: I recommend not redirecting, and not handling this at the server level. Simply check the subdomain with PHP and use the subdomain to fetch the account-specific information to display.

Comment: No, you've misunderstood. In your CodeIgnitor controller, simply var_dump($_SERVER) and look at the output. In the 'HTTP_HOST' key, you should see your domain name including subdomain. Write some code (like my example above) that extracts the subdomain, then pass this subdomain to your models to fetch whatever data you need, then load your views.

In this way, you'll end up with ONE codebase that is the same regardless of the number of subdomains you're hosting. If you have to write any additional code or server configs with each new subdomain, something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance

Comment: You're welcome. Since this answers your question, will you please select it as the answer?